# How to add working place autocomplete by passing paramerter

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Im not able to get place autocomplete so what should i do?

```
<input class="form-control" name="loc[]" onkeypress="return initialize(input);" required>
```

js code:

```
function initialize(input) {

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `onkeypress` event, `Autocomplete` will handle that for you. Just pass your `input` element and some `options` to the `Autocomplete` constructor.

Example:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places"></script>

<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Cities in US">
```

**-- Update --**
Using dynamically created `input` elements.

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var options=[{placeholder:"Cities in US",options:{types:["(cities)"],componentRestrictions:{country:"us"}}},{placeholder:"Cities in FR",options:{types:["(cities)"],componentRestrictions:{country:"fr"}}}];

function addAutocomplete (elem, options) {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(elem, options);
}

function crateAutoCompleteInputs ( count, optoins ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    input.placeholder = optoins[i].placeholder;
    form.appendChild(input);
    addAutocomplete(input, options[i].options)
  }
}

crateAutoCompleteInputs(2, options)
```

```css
input {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places"></script>

<form></form>
```

Comment: i dont want to use id because i have to dynamic input with different id

Comment: You don't have to select the element by its `id`, all you have to do is pass it to the `Autocomplete`. That's it. Where is the problem ?

Comment: I have made an update using dynamically created `input` elements.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Happy coding. ;)

Comment: How we can add search for city only in this example